# The value of the local variable variable is not used

Tags: java, eclipse

hi I'm new in this I don't know nothing about this if you can help me please I will apreciate.

Here is my tried of code

package paquete;

```
class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int variable;
    variable = 5;

    System.out.println("variable");

}
```

}

that is the mistake that eclipse give me it says that the mistake is int variable; I don't know why when i created the class main i selected public class main because it doesn't show me class default I think that is the mistake but I can selected. please if someone can help me.

Comment: Try `System.out.println(variable);` instead.

Answer (score 3):

The quotes around the print parameter make it a regular old string. If you want to print the variable value itself, leave out the double quotes. As mentioned before, make it `System.out.println(variable);`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you have declared a variable, 'variable' on this line

```
   int variable;
```

But you never use that variable. However if you change your println statement, you can make this warning disappear

```
System.out.println("variable: " + variable);
```

Answer (score 1):

By putting quotes around variable in `System.out.println("variable");` you are outputting the string (word) variable. When you want to output the literal value of the variable, you don't put quotes around it.
For example `System.out.println(variable);` would output `5` (as that is what you assigned to `variable`

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are trying to print `variable` text

```
 System.out.println("variable");
```

so change to

```
  System.out.println(variable);
```